# Iris-recognition System OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, iris-recognition

I've been searching for iris recognition implementations. I just see Matlab implementations only. why python doesn't have while python has more extensive and mature libraries?

How can I create my own iris-recognition system? can you help to define the road map?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok the question is extremely broad! what recognition? image, features? what is the libraries you what to use?! (opencv/tensorflow/pytorch) is there any hardware limits?! (CPU/GPU/mobile device/...) how much do you know about each will also help the details of the road map

Comment: @a-sam **Thank you for your reply.**

1- I want to extract the features of an eye so I can distinguish b/w to personals.

2- I'm very proficient in OpenCV and tensorflow. 

3- I'm currently using my laptop but in the future, I'm may be port it to the raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Now that we know the problem:

The first step is to find implement-ready codes, i recommend you to take a look at these:

1. [G6-iris-recognition python package](https://pypi.org/project/G6-iris-recognition/)
2. [iris-recognition by thuyngch in github (python)](https://github.com/thuyngch/Iris-Recognition)
3. [papers with code about iris-recognition](https://paperswithcode.com/task/iris-recognition)

then if the codes above did not help (which is highly unusual), you have to make these steps:

- first search the available papers in this field, see the designs
- if you like to implement the pipeline via neural networks

  1. train a CNN network in Tensorflow
  2. port it into OpenCV for compatibility with every device, take a look at [this link](https://jeanvitor.com/tensorflow-object-detecion-opencv/) for example
- if you like to develop your algorithm via hand-customed algorithms, i highly recommend following a paper, this way is richly researched in the literature and is mature.

hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you direction. this would help me alot.